# Crashes when I Click on Fragment Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, email

Trying to make a button when press would open up e-mail. Sorry for being a noob only beginner. Any help would be awesome, thank you
Crashes when I click on fragment not sure whats wrong, again any help is much appreciated

Heres code:

```
 public class Fragment_7 extends Fragment{
private Button button;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_7,
            container, false);

    final Context context = getActivity();

    Button button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button);

            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    sendEmail(context, new String[]{"info@bottlecapp.com"}, "Sending Email", "App Development", "");
                }
            });
            return view;
            }

 public static void sendEmail(Context context, String[] recipientList,
        String title, String subject, String body) {
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipientList);

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);

    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, title));

     }
 }





 06-15 18:28:56.719: E/AndroidRuntime(553): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 06-15 18:28:56.719: E/AndroidRuntime(553): java.lang.NullPointerException
 06-15 18:28:56.719: E/AndroidRuntime(553):     at      com.bottlecapp.bottlecapp.Fragment_7.onCreateView(Fragment_7.java:24)
 06-15 18:28:56.719: E/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
 06-15 18:28:56.719: E/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
 06-15 18:28:56.719: E/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
 06-15 18:28:56.719: E/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
 06-15 18:28:56.719: E/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
 06-15 18:28:56.719: E/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
 06-15 18:28:56.719: E/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
 06-15 18:28:56.719: E/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 06-15 18:28:56.719: E/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 06-15 18:28:56.719: E/AndroidRuntime(553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
 06-15 18:28:56.719: E/AndroidRuntime(553):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 06-15 18:28:56.719: E/AndroidRuntime(553):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 06-15 18:28:56.719: E/AndroidRuntime(553):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 06-15 18:28:56.719: E/AndroidRuntime(553):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 06-15 18:28:56.719: E/AndroidRuntime(553):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since getView returns what you inflate inside onCreateView, call it inside onCreateView will return null. Also the method must returns a view object. Change it this way:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_7,
        container, false);

final Context context = getActivity();

Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sendEmail(context, new String[]{",com"}, "Sending Email", "", "");
            }
        });
    return view;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked but now getting error on public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)

Comment: This method must return a result of type View
 - overrides 
  android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onCreateView

Comment: you missed  the return statement

Comment: Thank you so much! Work! Awesome :D I will accepte your answer as soon as I can

Comment: Although now I have no errors, it just crashes every time I click on the fragment

Comment: Button button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button);

Comment: It has to be Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button)

Comment: you are welcome. next time read carefully the people`s answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Change `final Context context = Fragment_7.this;`

with `final Context context = getActivity();`

Comment: Thank you, that worked but now getting error on  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState)

Comment: The method has to return a View object. So you can return the view you inflated.

Comment: Although now I have no errors, it just crashes every time I click on the fragment